# Render Vue.js x-template with underscore.js template function

Tags: vue.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I have a Vue.js x-template render script and would like to use Underscore.js `_.template()` templating engine instead of the default logic-less Handlebars syntax. As I need to add if loops and some additional JS logic, which Handlebars syntax does not provide. How can I implement such as solution?

Vue component code:

```
Vue.component('tmpl-heading',
  template: '#tmpl-heading',
  props: ['settings']
)
```

X-template script tag:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="tmpl-heading">
<h1>{{ settings.text }}</h1>
</script>
```

Comment: Why not use Vue's templating logic? `v-if`, `v-for`, etc

Comment: That's what I am currently doing. But this requires additional markup in some cases, which I want to avoid by using a templating engine where the JS logic doesn't need to be attached to HTML tags.